# PocoDynamo - use existing table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, servicestack, pocodynamo

Suppose I have a already existing table in DynamoDB, how do I register it with PocoDynamo

The type "SomeTable" points to different tables in prod and stg environments. Is there a way to register the type with table name or set the table name some other way.

```
_pocoClient.PutItem<SomeTable>(item)
```

Is there a way to use existing table with PocoDynamo ?

Note: I create tables using terraform, dont want to use PocoDynamo to create infra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) you just need to call `RegisterTable` to "register" the table and its schema with PocoDynamo, i.e:

```
db.RegisterTable<SomeTable>();
```

You can programmatically change the table name (On Startup before calling InitSchema()) by registering the table with:

```
var metadata = DynamoMetadata.RegisterTable<SomeTable>();
metadata.Name = "DbTableName";
```

After registering and configuring tables, calling `InitSchema` will only create the tables that don't already exist:

```
db.InitSchema();
```

If you want the DynamoDB Table to have a different Name than the .NET Type name you can use the [Alias attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#related-tables), e.g:

```
[Alias("DbTableName")]
public class SomeTable
{
    //..
}
```

Note: PocoDynamo is a code-first typed .NET client meaning that it expects the DynamoDB Tables to be created exactly how it would create it, it's not useful for mapping to existing tables generated with different conventions.

Comment: Even if i do this, my table name will be "DbTableName", i want it to be different in staging and production environments

Comment: Also i dont want to call the InitSchema, cause all infra should be created by terraform outside the application

Comment: A db.RegisterTable<SomeTable>("Table Name"); method will be nice. Would you consider a feature request ?

Comment: @Sunny As per my answer, if the tables already exist `InitSchema()` wont create them. I've updated my answer to show how you can programmatically change the table name used.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I got it to work                                                                 
 using var metaTableData = _pocoClient.GetTableMetadata<T>();
            metaTableData.Name = tableName;

Comment: I got the point with initSchema, the above code works without that as well. But cant use that still because don't want people accidentally creating tables from code.

Comment: metaTableData.Name = tableName, Feels a bit hackish. A proper method call would have been good.

Comment: @Sunny Yes that's how you can fetch the metadata after its registered, but it's still should only be initialized **once on startup** (i.e. not at runtime, it's not ThreadSafe). You don't have to call `InitSchema()` it's only purpose atm is to create missing tables but its expected that it is called after tables are registered should there need to be any post initialization logic that needs to be executed prior to use. The Type name convention and [Alias] attributes are the official APIs for configuring the table name, modifying the metadata manually ends up with the same result.

Comment: Thanks. I think you need to edit var metadata = db.RegisterTable<SomeTable>(); to var metadata = db.GetTableMetadata<SomeTable>(); in your code example.

Comment: @Sunny Just noticed `IPocoDynamo.RegisterTable<T>` discards the metadata to return a fluent API, I've updated my answer to use `DynamoMetadata.RegisterTable<T>` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208966/discussion-between-sunny-and-mythz).